# How can I get Silverlight + Amazon Instant Video to work with my browser's proxy?

Tags: google-chrome, vpn, proxy, silverlight

I have a VPN subscription which has an HTTP proxy service. I use Chrome on Windows 7, and I have my proxy set up through the proxy switchysharp extension. Basically, it works. Sites are detected with the autoswitching rules and it connects no problem. With Amazon instant video, however, it doesn't work. The Amazon site itself works with the proxy, but when trying to load a video I get a location error. I can only assume that this is something with silverlight not detecting the proxy correctly.

It *does* work with Netflix. I have that set up with proxy autoswitching rules and it works flawlessly. Amazon also works when I set the VPN/proxy settings *in Windows*. Initially I assumed that the Amazon video service is simply using URLs that don't match the amazon.com matching rule I had set up, but it *doesn't* work even if I turn off auto switching on the proxy and just leave it at a browser-wide "on" setting. This leads me to believe that something in the Silverlight plugin is going around my Chrome proxy settings and getting my real IP. It then checks that and finds my location.

Is there any way to make Silverlight work without changing the system proxy/VPN settings? I enjoy the versatility offered by automatic switching and would prefer not to lose that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to give an update, it seems that this is impossible. Silverlight goes directly to the system proxy settings, so anything at the browser level won't work. I'm assuming that Netflix does all of its regional IP checking from the site and not within the plugin itself while Amazon videos have the actual IP check within Silverlight, thus circumventing browser proxy settings.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh180774%28v=vs.95%29.aspx):

> In networks where a proxy server exists, special settings on the client may be required before streaming will work in Silverlight. In general, Silverlight looks at system settings only to make a decision about proxy server configuration. Therefore, specifying a proxy setting in Mozilla Firefox, which has its own proxy settings distinct from the operating system, will not affect the way streaming works in either Windows or Macintosh platforms.

---

Forgot about this question, but I later found that the best and easiest way to accomplish this was with a DNS proxy.